# VSCode: How to configure formatter with vue and eslint

Tags: vue.js, eslint, visual-studio-code

I want to have the option to "Format Document" according to the rules in my `.eslintrc` file.

I have the ESLint and Vetur extensions.

Currently the project is configured without semicolons. But whenever I use the "Format Document" function it adds a bunch of semicolons, which tells me that it's not following my lint config.

I tried tweaking a bunch of settings of both ESLint and Vetur, but nothing I do seems to make it follow the config. I am lost as to how the whole thing works, what takes precedence, etc...

Relevant ones:

```
"eslint.format.enable": true,
"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "prettier-eslint",
"vetur.format.enable": true,
```

Answer (score 3):

I had created an issue with vetur earlier last week, and this specific `prettier-eslint` issue has been fixed by the upstream.

https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/2480

https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/commit/005669957593f2d862b9c4057e6cbc2163340b30

Install modules to your project folder:

```
yarn add --dev eslint prettier prettier-eslint
```

Make sure to set your `settings.json` to:

```
"vetur.useWorkspaceDependencies": true
"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.scss": "prettier",
"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.css": "prettier",
"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "prettier-eslint",
"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "prettier",
```

set `vue` extension to use vetur for default formatting:

```
"[vue]": {
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur",
}
```

You don't need `"eslint.format.enable": true,` unless you use `eslint` for other things, since the vetur is handling the formatting :

Answer (score 2):

I using this in vscode settings.json for vscode version 1.52

```
{
      // 窗口失去焦点自动保存 
      "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
      // 编辑粘贴自动格式化 
      "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
      // 通过使用鼠标滚轮同时按住 Ctrl 可缩放编辑器的字体 
      "editor.mouseWheelZoom": false,
      // 行太长自动换行 
      "editor.wordWrap": "on",
      "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript",
        "javascriptreact",
        "html",
        "vue",
      ],
      "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
      },
      "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/macbeans/flutter",
      "dart.debugExternalLibraries": false,
      "dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
      "workbench.editorAssociations": [],
      "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "js-beautify-html",
      "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
        "js-beautify-html": {
          "wrap_attributes": "auto"
        }
      },
      "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "none",
      "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
      },
      "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.ts": "vscode-typescript"
    }
```